# Uninstalling 360 Security

Tags: uninstallation

I'm trying to delete 360 Security from my phone ( Samsung J 6 3 ), and it is activated as my device Administrator, when I go to deactivate the device administrative permission it shuts down my settings. How can i get rid of this app?

Comment: What happens if you  open the app page in Playstore and try to uninstall?

Comment: It asked me to deactivate the app as an administrator.  And that action causes the settings to shut down .

Answer (score 0):

Try to repeat this step in safe mode. You can access safe mode by these steps.

> Power off your device by holding down the Power button and then tapping on Power off.
>   Power on your device by holding down the Power button. As soon as the Samsung Logo pops up, press and hold down the Volume Down key until your device as rebooted.
>   You will now be able to see Safe Mode down the near the bottom left of the screen. 
>   To exit safe mode just reboot the device.

Hope it helped.

Comment: In safe mode the same thing happen it shuts down the setting app.

Answer (score -1):

Funny things happen .I updated the 360 security app and then went back and the device administrator was deactivated .don't ask me why but it seemed to help .Thanks everyone for you answers.